# Expired permesso, but valid student visa

Tags: visas, transit-visas, italian-residents, jamaican-citizens

I'm currently a Jamaican national studying in Italy since September of last year. My student visa is valid till the 4th of September this year and my Permesso di soggiorno (residence permit) expires on August 31st. My institution bought tickets for my return flight on the 1st of September where I'll transit from Venice to Frankfurt to Jamaica in the same day. They informed me today that there's a problem since my return ticket is for the day after my permit expires, however, I've left the Schengen area already this year and never have they once asked to see my permit. Will I have any problems leaving Europe without an expired permit and valid student visa?

Comment: Under the Schengen codes, it is quite clear that a valid visa and a valid residence permit are essentially the same thing, and you only need one or the other.  I don't know what Italian law has to say on the matter, however.  But since you'll be leaving the Schengen area in Germany, it may not matter from a practical standpoint.

Comment: @phoog do you have a reference that I may refer to? I tried searching on the internet but I can't find any authoritative source on this matter.

Comment: The current [consolidated version of the Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407), Art. 8(3)(ii): "verification that the travel document is accompanied, where applicable, by the requisite **visa or residence permit**" (emphasis added). Also, note how nobody ever asked for your card. If the visa were not sufficient by itself, they certainly would have asked for the card.  But Italian law also applies, which is why I have not posted an answer.

Answer (score 2):

From this [Travel SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109382/can-i-travel-to-italy-with-an-expired-permesso-di-soggiornon) question:

> The IATA statement reflects a Directive of the Italian Government's Interior Ministry which allows one to leave and return to Italy with an expired Permesso di Soggiorno, as long as one has the “ricevuta.”

You are allowed to exit Italy with it expired. **You will be fine**.