# UK visa from Italy

Tags: visas, uk

I am a Nepali national residing here in Italy for my PhD studies. I want to apply for the UK visitor visa but my permesso di soggiorno is expired right now and I have applied for its renewal, so I just have the receipt (ricevuta). Am I eligible to apply for the UK visitor visa and travel, and also travel back to Italy with the receipt I have?
Waiting for the reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see the question I linked. There's no requirement to prove residence in order to apply for a UK visa. Your receipt proves you are legally present in Italy. Also see this answer which answers the second half of your question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109382/can-i-travel-to-italy-with-an-expired-permesso-di-soggiorno